# How do I make a login using SQLITE3 in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, authentication

ay yo this is my 1st post don't bully me... so im tryna make a login things using SQLITE3 in python (the module) and im trash (also if there is a better database module then can u tell me in I could use MySQL but I dont need to store 103213021032103123123 data so) and im not sure what to do here the code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("pooptest123.db")
c = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE login(Username VARCHAR, Passwords VARCHAR)")
    conn.commit


def enter():
    Username = input("Create username: ")
    Password = input("Create password: ")
    c.execute(
        "INSERT INTO login (Username, Passwords) VALUES (?, ?)", (Username, Password,)
    )
    conn.commit()


create_table()
enter()


def read():
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE "Username" == Username'
    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'Passwords' == Password"
    c.execute(sql, sql2)
    conn.commit


read()


def loginlol():
    sure = input("Login?(Y OR N: ")
    if sure == "y" or sure == "Y":
        b = input("Username: ")
        ca = input("Password: ")
        if b == sql:
            print("Username correct!")
        if c == sql2:

            print("Password correct!")
            print("Logging in...")


loginlol()

conn.close()
```

and it says this:

```
File "C:\Users\dontlookhere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\login.py", line 20, in <module>
    read()
  File "C:\Users\dontlookhere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\login.py", line 18, in read
    c.execute(sql, sql2)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 49 supplied.
```

sry im dumb so and trash with oop and idk what im doing ok anyways thx

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do in `def read():` ?

Comment: im tryna grab the username and passwrod from the table and like make them in variables "sq1" and "sq12"

Comment: this is not good idea `c.execute(sql, sql2)`. It doesn't runs two queries but only first query and it use second query as arguments for first. You have to use `c.execute(sql)` and `c.execute(sql2)`. But why not use `WHERE "Username" == Username AND 'Passwords' == Password"`. But in query you have to use real username and password from user - `execute(sql, (username, password))`

Comment: separated queries are not good because it check only username without password or only password without username. It will give `True` when you use pair `your username` and `my password` but it is not correct result. It has to get `True` only for pair `your username` and `your password` or for pair `my username` and `my password`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first (but not last) mistake is

```
 c.execute(sql, sql2)
```

`execute()` can't run two queries. It runs `sql` as  query but text in `sql2` it uses as list of arguments for `sql`.

See your other `execute`:

```
c.execute(
    "INSERT INTO login (Username, Passwords) VALUES (?, ?)", (Username, Password,)
)
```

you have only one query `INSERT` and list of arguments `(Username, Password,)`

---

Other mistake is that you expect that `SELECT` will assign result to variables `sql` and `sql2` but it doesn't work this way. `execute` uses query `sql` but after that you have to use `c.fetchall()` or `c.fetchone()` to get result from database.

Simply you have to get some tutorial for databases in Python and learn all from scratch.

---

**EDIT:**

Other big mistake is that you use two SELECT

```
'SELECT * FROM login WHERE "Username" == Username'
"SELECT * FROM login WHERE 'Passwords' == Password"
```

but this way you check `username` without `password` or `password` without `username` but you don't check `password` and `username` as pair.

Someone may use `your useraname` and `my password` and it will give `True` but it should gives `True` only for pair `your username` and `your password` or for pair `my username` and `my password`. You should check it in one query using

```
 WHERE Username == "?" AND Passwords == "?"
```

like

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username == "?" AND Passwords == "?"', (username, password)`
```

But there is other problem - you shouldn't keep password in plain text but you should keep it encrypted. But it is problem for different question.

---

More or less:

```
def read(username, password):

    sql = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username == "?" AND Passwords == "?"'
    c.execute(sql, (userame, password)
    result = c.fetchone()

    return result
```

---

**EDIT:**

I see another problem - in your database you may have the same `username` many times - you should make it `UNIQUE`

---

**EDIT:**

Example code.

For test at start it drops table and create new one but normally you should create table only once.

I add `UNIQUE` so it will raise error when you try to create second user with the same name.

It still need to encrypt `password`

If `username` and `password` is correct then `check()` returns single row with user data. If `username` or `password` is wrong then it returns `None`.

Eventually in `check()` you can create query which use only `Username = ?` to get user data and later it checks `password` in this data without usign second `sql`. This way you may get user data even if he put wrong `password`.

```
import sqlite3


def create_table():
    query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS login"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    
    query = "CREATE TABLE login(Username VARCHAR UNIQUE, Password VARCHAR)"
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

def enter(username, password):
    query = "INSERT INTO login (Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?)"
    cursor.execute(query, (username, password))
    conn.commit()

def check(username, password):
    query = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?'
    cursor.execute(query, (username, password))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()
    print('[DEBUG][check] result:', result)
    return result

def loginlol():
    answer = input("Login (Y/N): ")

    if answer.lower() == "y":
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        if check(username, password):
            print("Username correct!")
            print("Password correct!")
            print("Logging in...")
        else:
            print("Something wrong")

# --- main ---

conn = sqlite3.connect("pooptest123.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

create_table()

Username = input("Create username: ")
Password = input("Create password: ")

enter(Username, Password)

#check(Username, Password)

loginlol()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: thx and i should learn from scratch I haven't done this in a long time, and I just refreshed my mind with a 5 min tutorial on yt and thinking I was a cyber security expert now so thx for the help

Comment: also love how u kept the names like "loginlol" and "pooptest123," and by those two phrases alone you can guess I am obv very mature